# Is there a way to install ODBC drivers on github actions?

Tags: odbc, github-actions

I'm trying to build a CI/CD pipeline for my flask app in Azure using Github Actions.

I have been able to build the workflows, however, when running the tests (using pytest),
I'm getting the error

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

It seems that is due to the missing odbc driver on the Ubuntu VM/container used by GitHub actions to run the code.

So I tried to install the drivers in the building environement using:

```
- name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          
          curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

          curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

          apt-get update
          ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
          ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
          echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
          source ~/.bashrc
          # optional: for unixODBC development headers
          sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

In the same way is suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

However, when running the action I receive the following error:

```
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
E: This command can only be used by root.

100   983  100   983    0     0   8776      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8776
(23) Failed writing body
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

That seems to be caused by the curl commands.

So my question is. What's the best way to test my app using GitHub actions?
Do I need to install the odbc driver? If yes, how can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should only need to apt-get the package to install the driver:

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install Microsoft ODBC
        run: sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql18 -y
```

that successfully installs for me. Worth pointing out though that when you connect you'll need to use the mapped port to the container:

```
        env:
          PORT: ${{ job.services.mssql.ports[1433] }}
```

this assumes SQL Server was setup like:

```
      mssql:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
        ports: [1433]
        env:
          MSSQL_PID: Developer
          SA_PASSWORD: iugeshrigsuerbiwer
          ACCEPT_EULA: Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Because all of the above worked for me only sometimes for some reason. I wrote an action that follows the exact instructions from microsoft to install mssql odbc drivers for any distro. Here https://github.com/Yarden-zamir/install-mssql-odbc. If anyone stumbling onto here like me in the future and finds this useful that would be awesome.

You can use it like

```
      - uses: Yarden-zamir/install-mssql-odbc@main
```

or

```
# all inputs
      - uses: Yarden-zamir/install-mssql-odbc@main
        with:
          ODBC_VERSION: 17
          DISTRO: Alpine
          DOCS_URL: https://yarden-zamir.com/alternate-docs-path.md
          REMOVE_EXITS: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the commands with elevated privileges.
Simply, add `shell` with `sudo` like so:

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    ...
    sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
  shell: sudo bash {0}
```